# What is my real name?

Tags: riddle, mathematics, chemistry

> My Father is a Chemist
>   My Mother is a Mathematician
>   They call me `iron59`

**What is my real name?**

Comment: @ABcDexter Why uppercase for "Father" and "Mother"? Are THEY significant?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος There can be hints given by the OP. so we should respect the caps as provided.

Comment: @ABcDexter Thanks for editing by the way.

Comment: @ABcDexter: But the OP never capitalized "Mother"; that was entirely your invention (unless you based it on a now-deleted comment).  But, now that we know the answer, it looks like the capitalization was never meant to be a hint.  (If anything, IMHO, "Iron" should have been capitalized.)

Comment: @PeregrineRook Oh my bad. I presumed it was.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your name is

> Felix

Because

> Iron is **Fe** (chemical symbol) and $59$ is $LIX$ (Roman numerals)

Comment: very easy for a first question.

Comment: I since went to Google to see if there was a real person of the same name with parents of those professions so I could add a surname and I saw that the question is already "out there".

Comment: ok then. It can't be helped.

Comment: Do you know the **original** source? If so do attribute the question to them. Also, welcome to Puzzling!

Comment: I just heard it from my friend :)

Comment: I'd be tempted to say the mother was a Historian not a Mathematician!

Comment: I think that would be too broad.

Answer (score 12):

Ok, this is a slightly farfetched, but female answer

> FELICIA

because

> **Fe**(chemical symbol) + **L**(12) + **I**(9) + **C**(3) + **I**(9) + **Y**(25) + **A**(1)

Comment: nice answer too.

Comment: Well, how can you remove a letter without explaining why?

Answer (score 6):

> ## $\Huge\text{Feebs}$

My Father is a Chemist
my Mother a mathematician
and they call me `iron59`

> It has to do with [chemistry](/questions/tagged/chemistry) and [mathematics](/questions/tagged/mathematics), so the first part is probably "Fe", the chemical symbol for Iron. The second part is the base 16 representation of $59$, $(EB)_{10_{16}}$. The "s" is added to look more like a name.